# c# & mono console app - DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, .net, razor, xamarin, mono

I am building a console app in c#/mono. I want to do some razor parsing. I use the line below to get the FileInfo object for the razor template.

```
var applicationLayout = new DirectoryInfo ("../../../path/to/the/folder").GetFiles ("Application.cshtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories) [0];
```

This runs fine when running it in debug mode, from Xamarin studio.

However, when running the exe from the command line like

```
$ mono Path/to/project/bin/Debug/MyConsoleApp.exe
```

It throws

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at Reflect.JobProcessing.JobWorker.Start () <0x37e10e0 + 0x00533> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Reflect.Web.v2.JobProcessor.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) <0x6c7ec8 + 0x0018b> in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at Reflect.JobProcessing.JobWorker.Start () <0x37e10e0 + 0x00533> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Reflect.Web.v2.JobProcessor.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) <0x6c7ec8 + 0x0018b> in <filename unknown>:0
```

This is not very descriptive. By outputting some markers to the console I have narrowed the culprit down to the statement above. Before that alle code executes fine but as soon as that statement is hit, it crashed.

Any ideas? :-)

=== EDIT ===

```
public void Start ()
{
    ReportHeading ("Job worker started");
    Report ("I am worker " + Guid.ToString());
    Report ("I am working on queue(s): " + string.Join(", ", Queues));

    while (_work) {

        Report ("Polling for jobs at " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString ());

        var jobModel = JobConfig.CurrentStore.PollForJob (Queues);
        var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var endTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        double timeDiff = 0;

        if (jobModel != null) {
            ReportHeading("Job " + jobModel.Guid.ToString () + " started at " + startTime.ToString ());
            var job = InstantiateJob (jobModel);
            MarkJobAsStarted (jobModel, job);
            try
            {
                job.Perform (jobModel.JobArgs);
                MarkJobAsCompeleted (jobModel, job);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                job.Exception = ex;
                MarkJobAsFailed (jobModel, job);
                ReportHeading ("JOB ERROR!");
                Report ("Exception: " + job.Exception.Message);
                Report("Inner exception: " + job.Exception.InnerException.Message);
                Report ("Continuing...");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Report("No jobs available");
        }

        endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        timeDiff = (endTime - startTime).TotalSeconds;

        if(jobModel != null) 
        {
            Report ("Job completed in " + timeDiff.ToString() + " seconds");
        }

        if (timeDiff < PollInterval) {
            var sleepTime = (int)(PollInterval - timeDiff);
            Report ("Sleeping for " + sleepTime + " seconds");
            Thread.Sleep (sleepTime * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DirectoryInfo.GetFiles is not even on stack trace.

Comment: Hi @Evk. Correct. That's the crazy part. However, `Reflect.JobProcessing.JobWorker.Start ()` method is mentioned. I added that to my questions. Does that help?

Comment: Not much. Something throws NotImplementedException somewhere, but what and where I don't see from the provided code.

Comment: Yeah, info is really limit. Thanks anyway. Ill investigate further.

Comment: @Evk, do you have any idea how to debug this? Since it's running fine when started from Xamarin Studio...?

Comment: Hooked it up to the Xamarin/MonoDevelop debugger under Run -> Debug application.